# Accessing a file in C++ code using the "./program < file" command line argument

Tags: c++, bash, command-line-arguments

I'm sure this is an extremely simple issue - I've been searching for an answer everywhere but I think my problem is that I don't know the right terminology to use while searching.

I'm currently working on an assignment for a class using C++. Essentially, I need to read a file into a C++ program, do some stuff, and create an output - I've done all of this already. I was accessing the file by just using

```
fstream file;
file.open("file.txt");'
```

in the .cc file itself, and that was working fine. However, I just saw in the instructions for this assignment that this is not how the instructor will be testing the program - instead, they will simply run my executable like this:
`./program < file.txt`

I'm familiar with using command line arguments within C++ programs, and I'm able to make the program work no problem when running `./program file.txt` (just passing the file as an argument), but I can't figure out how to do it the way the instructor is asking for. Worse off, I can't figure out how to actually search for the answer since I don't know the correct terminology yet (I'm simultaneously only in the first few weeks of my UNIX class).

Is anyone able to help point me in the right direction? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Use `std::cin` instead. This is a "bash"-ism. They are piping the contents of the file to your program via stdin. Might be more of a "sh"-ism, I don't know that stuff super great.

Comment: @sweenish Thank you so much! That was all I needed, the program is now working!

Comment: If you've found a solution yourself, then the question can be deleted.

Comment: You could make your program flexible in this respect: If a file name is present in `argv[1]`, you read from this file. If no argv is empty, you read from stdin. If you implement it like this, both `program file.txt` and `program < file.txt` will work.